# Which procedure makes the most sense for a Canadian Visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, canada, family

I’m going to be flying over to Canada in a few weeks, I am from the UK.

As things stand I will go on a tourist visa which should give me 6 months (180 days/179 days to be sure?).

What is my best approach to obtaining a visa and looking to stay in Canada longer term, rather than the tourist based months? Is it fine to go on a tourist visa and then progress from there?

I’m not the most clued up with this and don’t want to make an error that I look back on as, "Oh, I should have done that".

Comment: I don't know whether the rules have changed since I last knew them, so this isn't an answer, only something you should be aware of.  When my wife did what you are trying to do, she had to apply from, and then remain, outside of Canada until her immigration application was approved.  So, if you move here first, you might end up making things more complicated for yourself.

Comment: While on a tourist visa: DON'T EVEN THINK ABOUT WORKING in Canada. That can "earn" you a 5-year deportation order or - the worst case - even a livelong ban. Spousal sponsoring can be possible for a married couple. I'd recommend consulting the Canadian high commission in the UK. There are also comprehensive information on the websites of the Canadian federal government. You should go here first: https://www.canada.ca/en/services/immigration-citizenship.html

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Comment: You've asked a question that would need a lot more details for us to offer suggestions. What is the basic reason for your visit and why do want to extend your stay? Is it truly a visit, or do actually plan on *residing* in Canada? Do you have any family there? If you are in a relationship with someone there, would you consider getting married? What is your professional background? Educational background? How would you support yourself during your stay? You've taken out critical information that someone would need to offer a useful answer.

Comment: If I edit this question again, I'm going to lock it down so that *nobody* (except my fellow mods) can change it. I will not be participating in an edit war. Please put back in the information that we would need to answer this question. You can be selective if you like, it's your question - within the understanding of the license agreement. But I'd atleast leave in the details that answers the questions in my previous comment.

Comment: One important thing about immigration (my expertise is in US rules, but I'm originally Canadian) is that _intent _ is very important. If you get a 6 month status or visa and your intent at the time you got it was to find a way to extend it, you are breaking the law

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question as you, but I found this questionnaire on the Government of Canada website.

https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/come-canada-tool.html

Give it a try, I found it helpful.